# How to inspect child element's DOM in React before its parent is rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Let there be a class A that creates an element of class B in its `render` method. The rendering of class A depends on computed size of the element generated by class B, i.e. it needs to know something about *rendered* DOM of the child to render its own DOM.

The problem is that lifecycle events happen in the following order:

- B renders
- A renders
- B mounts
- A mounts

and it's impossible to get even a `ref` to B while A renders.

I came up with two solutions:

1. Pass callback `onKnownDims` as a prop to B. Let the first rendering occur with some incorrect dimensions. When `B` gets mounted, it calls `onKnownDims` that changes A's state, that leads to an immediate second rendering. This way there's some short time range when DOM is incorrect. Even though it's possible to solve this problem with some hacks (`display: none` etc.), the solution doesn't sound sane.
2. In A's `componentWillMount` call `this.render` and pass its return into `ReactDOM.render`. Even though it's deprecated, it returns a reference to B that can be used to find dimensions from the resulting DOM and set these into A's state. Then reparent B's DOM from an off-screen parent element into A (this works because React's render doesn't care if root gets relocated in DOM). Otherwise (by using a callback) this approach doesn't work, because `componentWillMount` is synchronous.

Is there any way to do this properly (i.e. on the first render and without deprecated functionality)?

Comment: Is that order right? I thought it would be A mounts, B mounts, A renders, B renders?

Comment: @Chris [Certainly no mounting before rendering.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

Comment: Right of course, I was thinking willMount not didMount (as in point 2 you mentioend that lifecycle method)